# how can i download postgresql interactive installer for windows?

Tags: postgresql, download, edb

I tried to download Postgres interactive installer for my Window 10 laptop, and I got a message displaying "thank you for downloading Postgres, your download will begin momentarily, loading...(button)", but the download isn't ongoing, what can I do to download the interactive installer of postgres for my window 10 laptop.

Comment: Ask the people maintaining that website

Comment: If you are talking about this [EDB Postgres](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) then the site i shaving issues. I eventually got this error message "This function has crashed". I'm guessing it is related to the roll out of [New Releases](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-143-137-1211-1116-and-1021-released-2449/) today. I would check back later.